# Best way to restrict login to adjustable set of roles

Tags: shiro

I have the requirement that only certain user roles should be allowed to log in. The set of roles may change at runtime.

```java
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
subject.login(token);
```

Which implementation is the most appropriate / secure?

1. Lookup the user roles (outside of Shiro) before calling `subject.login()` and raise an `AuthenticationException` if no role is permitted.
2. Let the authenticationQuery of the JdbcRealm only return a password (via SQL JOIN), when a user has one of the permitted roles.
3. Log the user in, then check roles / permissions, and immediately logout and raise `AuthenticationException` if not permitted.
4. other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider user behavior here.  If your webapp makes it look like a user was unable to logout, (IMHO) the first thing the user will do is try again, the second thing is they will call the help desk and try to reset their password.

This depends on your actual application, (so take this with a grain of salt).  I'd suggest letting the user login and then blocking access e.g. show a 403 page with a ("You shall not pass" warning), or show a 404 (this is what GitHub does as it does NOT leak information that a valid page exists).

This also simplifies the Shiro implementation, just require a role/permission for your routes.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. For clarification I should have mentioned, that there are actually two separate applications with separate logins, but the same user directory. The access to the second application is restricted to a sub-set of users.

Comment: That was my guess. Assuming those users already know that resource exists, you are not leaking anything by redirecting them to a 403 page after they login, or redirecting back to the login page with an error saying they don't have access to this resource.

Comment: ok, I think i will 1. process the login, 2. check the permission on success. 3. if granted the page is redirected, else the user is logged out automatically with a warning and the possibility to re-login. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also let Shiro manage the role/permission check but configuring your routes:
`/** = authc, roles[yourRoleName]`